# How to loop through 2 or more array at once in an object

Tags: php

I have a php object containing two arrays and I need to loop through both array at once and display option for select. The `table->list` should come inside the value and `tables->title` should come inside option HTML output.

Here is my code:

```
$tables = new \stdClass();
$tables->list =  ['bmg_contact_us','bmg_volunteer'];
$tables->title = ['Contact us', 'Volunteer'];

<select name="bmg-forms" onchange="submission_frm.submit();">

<?php
foreach ($tables as $key => $table) {
 echo "<option value='" . $tables->list . "'>'" . $tables->title . "'</option>";    
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: in loop should be $table->list ?

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: The array $tables->list should come in value attribute of option and $tables->title array should come inside option

Comment: <option value="table_list"> table_title </option>

Comment: @AbhilashNarayan you can only accept one answer. Accept the answer suited you best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop the inner array and then use the key to get the title.

```
foreach ($tables->list as $key => $table) {
 echo "<option value='" . $table . "'>'" . $tables->title[$key] . "'</option>";    
}
```

Output:

```
<option value='bmg_contact_us'>'Contact us'</option>
<option value='bmg_volunteer'>'Volunteer'</option>
```

https://3v4l.org/i1dcT

Answer (score 1):

```
$tables = new \stdClass();
$tables->list =  ['bmg_contact_us','bmg_volunteer'];
$tables->title = ['Contact us', 'Volunteer'];
$options = array_combine($tables->list,$tables->title);//both array count must be same
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [bmg_contact_us] => Contact us
    [bmg_volunteer] => Volunteer
)
```

html:

```
<select name="bmg-forms" onchange="submission_frm.submit();">

<?php
foreach ($options as $key => $value) {
 echo "<option value='" . $key . "'>'" . $value . "'</option>";    
}
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to create an associated array (https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) and iterate over it.

In your example:

```
 $tables->options = [
    'bmg_contact_us' => 'Contact us', 
    'bmg_volunteer' => 'Volunteer'
 ];

 foreach ($tables->options as $value => $text) {
    echo("<option value='$value'>$text</option>");    
 }
```